# Question about Sarasvati, mother of Sarvabhauma

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, saraswati

It is mentioned in the Srimad Bhagavatam that in the period of the eighth Manu, the incarnation of the Supreme Personality of Godhead appears as the son of Devaguhya & Sarasvati.

> देवगुह्यात् सरस्वत्यां
>   सार्वभौम इति प्रभुः
>   स्थानं पुरन्दराद् धृत्वा
>   बलये दास्यतीश्वरः
>
> devaguhyāt sarasvatyāṁ
>   sārvabhauma iti prabhuḥ
>   sthānaṁ purandarād dhṛtvā
>   balaye dāsyatīśvaraḥ [SB 8.13.17](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/13/17)
>
> In the eighth manvantara, the greatly powerful Personality of Godhead Sārvabhauma will take birth. His father will be Devaguhya, and His mother will be Sarasvatī. He will take the kingdom away from Purandara [Lord Indra] and give it to Bali Mahārāja.

The Sarasvati that is mentioned here - Is it Goddess Saraswati ? Who is Devaguhya ?

Comment: Purandara is name of curent Indra. It's surprising he has the same name in next Manvantara too.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Purandara is the current Indra (who obviously has issues with sharing his position) from whom Sarvabhauma will take away the throne and pass it on to Bali, the next Indra.

Comment: @Surya But Purandara will die after Vaivasvara Manavantara. I thought Bali's Atma would take position of Indra in next Manvantara.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Apparently Mahabali who is in Sutala will attack Devaloka at the end of the Manvantara. I speculate it is because the current Indra has been traversing through various bodies across seven Manvantaras so it's the first time his soul will be denied access to Indrapadavi.

Comment: @Surya But why to attack when Devas are going to born again?